# Who maintains Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0

I am in active participation in Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow and Programmers.SE. It has been a great experience for me to discuss problems in Stack Exchange sites.

I was wondering who are the makers and creators of this community portal? Who is responsible for making rules and regulations, setting guidelines for the community? Is there a special **team of board members** operating the various stack exchange accounts or these are the **top users** who are responsible for maintaining these accounts and other regulations?

Comment: Start at: http://stackexchange.com/about.

Comment: Thanx. I am having a look at it.

Comment: What's the reason for downvotng this post.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj Lack of research, possibly.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj on any site in the Internet you can find who "operates" it in "about" page, usually found in the site footer. It's pretty basic, hence the downvotes here.

Comment: I do agree though that here is requires four steps: [local about page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) --> [Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) --> [Stack Exchange about page](http://stackexchange.com/about) --> [management](http://stackexchange.com/about/management)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx @GamecatisToonKrijthe, found the answer.

In 2008, Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky created site Stack Overflow

and here is the team who operates stack exchange accounts..

**[[Stack Exchange Team]](https://stackexchange.com/about/team)**